# What does "facility" mean in the context of fitness certification?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I want to host a fitness certification. So, i have to fill this [form](http://www.taebo.com/index.php?p=page&page_id=host_a_certification). But i didn't understand what *facility* means in this context therefore i can't find the best word to put in that field.

What does facility means in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming,facility here means 'building'. Often , a building constructed for special purposes (gym ,hospital ,school )is called a facility. :)

Correct me If I am sounding wrong or stupid :P

Comment: You are quite correct. A facility in this case would be where the original poster probably wishes to work once certified, or where they have been working. Most probably, the address of a gym.